# I can't see my faces in object mode in solid mode.

Tags: modeling

[image]

Why can't I see the outside faces of the object?

Comment: There is shown a cube extruded into the form of a small house and you can see its faces because they form that grey solid surface. Likely you ask about something else which doesn't seem to be clear from the question. [Edit] it to clarify

Comment: Are you possibly looking for *Edit mode*? Press `Tab` to toggle it

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot seems to be showing the faces it is supposed to show.

Is it possible that, since the 3D viewport lacks unambiguous lighting and depth clues, you are experiencing a **perspective reversal**?

[image]

( ↑ An example of "ambiguous figure", "reversible figure" or "bistable figure": [Schroeder stairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schroeder_stairs). Which plane (whether A or B) is in front is subjective, unless you are told that these stairs are built on the floor rather than on the ceiling, then A prevails. )

Should it be the case, it's a perception phenomenon, not Blender's fault. You must just convince yourself that what you are seeing are actually the outside faces.

Moving the view around (hold  <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> and move the mouse) might help.

[image]